# "Could not create unix socket lock file" with MySQL 5.7.10 on OS X 10.11.2

Tags: macos, mysql, homebrew, sockets, osx-el-capitan

I've been trying to install MySQL 5.7 on OS X El Capitan using Homebrew, however when it came to getting the server up and running, I cannot seem to get a lock file created.

When I run `mysqld_safe`, it logs errors to a file and the only relevant message that I saw was this:

`2015-12-13T19:48:09.270970Z 0 [ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.lock.`

Looking at the configuration, if I run `mysql_config | grep -- --socket`, I see this:

`--socket         [/tmp/mysql.sock]`

It *seems* that the socket is getting created for a split second, but if it tries to make the lock file, it aborts. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in mysql 5.7.

In my case, I am building a docker container. I went ahead and changed the version of mysql I installed to 5.6 through apt-get and it fixed the issue immediately.

```
apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
apt-get update
apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 mysql-server-5.6
```

Hope this helps.